# Mobiscroll Month and Year Picker View Handle Start and End Date

Tags: mobiscroll

I am using [Mobiscroll](http://demo.mobiscroll.com/datetime/month/#) Month and Year Picker View. In my scenario I have Start and End Date and I want to disable End Date based on Start Date and usual checks etc..

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Attiqe